# Opening data:text/plain window in chrome showing up blank

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.open

The current function is working and has been working for years, however within the last 3 weeks suddenly users on Chrome cannot access the plain text document, but is still working on other browsers.

Basically the function runs like this:

```
<a class="modo-link" target="_blank" data-modo="4%20Aether%20Hub%0A4%20Botanical%20Sanctum%0A1%20Blooming%20Marsh%0A3%20Forest%0A1%20Island%0A2%20Mountain%0A3%20Rootbound%20Crag%0A1%20Sheltered%20Thicket%0A2%20Spirebluff%20Canal%0A1%20Swamp%0A4%20Bristling%20Hydra%0A3%20Glorybringer%0A4%20Longtusk%20Cub%0A4%20Rogue%20Refiner%0A4%20Servant%20of%20the%20Conduit%0A2%20The%20Scarab%20God%0A4%20Whirler%20Virtuoso%0A2%20Abrade%0A4%20Attune%20with%20Aether%0A2%20Essence%20Scatter%0A4%20Harnessed%20Lightning%0A1%20Magma%20Spray%0A%0ASideboard%0A2%20Cartouche%20of%20Ambition%0A2%20Chandra's%20Defeat%0A1%20Confiscation%20Coup%0A3%20Negate%0A1%20Supreme%20Will%0A2%20Spell%20Pierce%0A1%20Hour%20of%20Glory%0A1%20Struggle%2FSurvive%0A2%20Vizier%20of%20Many%20Faces"><img src="https://227rsi2stdr53e3wto2skssd7xe-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/plugins/crystal-catalog-helper/assets/img/modologo.png"></a>

$('.modo-link').on('click', function() {
     var win = window.open('data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + $(this).attr('data-modo'), '_blank');
     win.focus();
});
```

Example is here:
https://www.channelfireball.com/articles/the-return-of-nationals/

Just find the "Temur Black" deck list and click the icon above the image example:  [Deckilst icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7ufS.png)

I can't seem to figure out what is causing it in Chrome to open a blank window when it used to work fine, could it be an SSL thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chromium team [intentionally deprecated and removed the ability to open data URLs](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM/GsIAQlemBQAJ). This change appears to be active as of Chrome 61.

Comment: Alright that is helpful then, guess my only solution is to not use them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting it to work using Ahmed's method but I had to decode the URI and replace the breaks with `<br>`, I think it will work fine.

```
var win = window.open(); 
win.document.write(decodeURIComponent($(this).attr('data-modo')).replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br/>'));
win.focus();
```

But if anyone has another answer to keep it using text let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working on chrome but you can use alternative solution like:

```
var w = window.open("");
w.document.write('Your Text Here');
```

It's working on all major browsers.

Comment: That sort of helps, but I need to keep it in a .txt file for quick download.